# UITableViewCell UI Testing

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to check the background colour of an UIImageView I have in a custom UITableViewCell in UI tests. I have tried looking online everywhere but can't seem to find an actual answer to doing this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the [XCUIElement Class Reference](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIElement.html). The ability to observe colors aren't exposed to us for functional testing.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667435/in-xctest-ui-testing-how-to-check-the-background-color-of-button-label-views), which provides an alternative to your situation.

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I hope it helps.